# MSSQL Mirroring equivalent to Oracle Data Guard Snapshot Standby

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2014, mirroring, dataguard

Does MSSQL support an operating mode on the failover partner / mirror that is functionally equivalent to Oracle database's Snapshot Standby mode?

ie A temporary active copy of the replicated database that can be open for read/write but can be reverted back to a replication target without rebuild?

Comment: I think [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-2017) is the closest thing, only because it satisfies being writable. However, I wouldn't recommend anyone implement it unless they're being punished for something egregious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirroring does NOT have this capability.  If you are using the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server then an Availability Group (MSSQL's successor to mirroring) with a readable secondary would do this, but you would be required to license both instances with EE licenses.

Comment: I believe they're looking for read/write.